# Microbit: Sprite does not move

Tags: bbc-microbit

I'm making a game where player 1 has to dodge the boulders that player 2 throws at them. Player 2 automatically throws a boulder if there is not a boulder already on the screen. The problem is that the boulder does not move.

[image: Boulder]

I've tried re-arranging the move and 500ms blocks around, and I've tried moving player 2 around, but it just creates another boulder.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the `if not is boulder deleted then` block that looks incorrect.

You only want to create the new `boulder` if the object *is* deleted.

I've done a test with `player2` being moved randomly and having the `not` in there displays the behaviour you describe.

For reference, this is my test code with the moving boulder

[image]